# How can I Remove suffixes and prefixes from words

Tags: prefix

how to remove prefixes and suffixes in notepad++
I have a text full of words
i want to remove the suffix -ment from all of them
i want the suffix ones to be removed not the ones in the middle of the words
same thing with prefixes only the ones in the beginning

Comment: *not the ones in the middle of the words* So you must replace `(suffix)(non-char)` with `(non-char)` (space, EOL, digit, comma, semicolon, etc.). The same for prefix.

Comment: thanks for answering
but I don't follow you
what do you mean?
would you please give some examples